# Single producer single consumer wait-free object container

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, lock-free

I have a fast producer thread and a slow consumer thread. The consumer processes as many objects as it can and simply ignores the rest in order to not slow down the producer. Therefore, I used a one-element wait-free single-producer single-consumer queue for passing objects to the consumer in a thread-safe manner. After taking one out, it should be filled back in by the producer before the consumer finishes processing the element. I was wondering about how to simplify this one-element edge case and came up with the following.

The `spsc_object` class reserves storage for a single object and achieves thread safety for a single writer and a single reader. It's inspired by `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue` and supports move semantics.

```
#ifndef SPSC_OBJECT_HH
#define SPSC_OBJECT_HH

#include <type_traits>
#include <new>
#include <atomic>

template<typename T>
class spsc_object {
    using storage_t = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type;

    storage_t storage_;
    std::atomic_bool occupied_;

public:
    bool write(const T& object)
    {
        const bool occupied = occupied_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        if (!occupied) {
            new (&storage_) T(object); // copy
            occupied_.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool write(T&& object)
    {
        const bool occupied = occupied_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        if (!occupied) {
            new (&storage_) T(std::move(object)); // move
            occupied_.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    template<typename Functor>
    bool read(Functor& functor)
    {
        const bool occupied = occupied_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        if (!occupied)
            return false;

        T& object = reinterpret_cast<T&>(storage_);
        functor(object);
        object.~T();

        occupied_.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        return true;
    }

    template<typename Functor>
    bool read(const Functor& functor)
    {
        const bool occupied = occupied_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        if (!occupied)
            return false;

        T& object = reinterpret_cast<T&>(storage_);
        functor(object);
        object.~T();

        occupied_.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        return true;
    }
};

#endif
```

It seems to work in a small test case I wrote but correctness is hard to verify. Considering performance, `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue` uses a read index and a write index (placed in different cache lines!) and one additional queue element to distinguish an empty queue from a full one. My container only uses an `std::atomic_bool` in addition to the object storage space, so it is definitely smaller and hopefully faster. I am not certain whether there could be a faster alternative to the `std::atomic_bool`. Maybe a processor-word sized variable is faster? Would two separate flags be useful to reduce contention? Did I miss anything else?

Edit: Here's my test case ([see Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/107a121d36bbe3a7)) that produces dummy objects and outputs which of those could be consumed. For some reason, there will be major gaps, i.e. large numbers of subsequent objects are not consumed. I guess that happens whenever `std::cout`'s buffer is flushed.

```
#include "spsc_object.hpp"

#include <cassert>
#include <atomic>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

struct test_t {
    int x, y;
    test_t(int x) : x(x), y(1) {}
    ~test_t() {
        y = 0;
    }
};

const int to_produce = 10000000;

spsc_object<test_t> object;
std::atomic_bool stop_consuming;

int producer()
{
    int written = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < to_produce; i++) {
        if (object.write(test_t(i)))
            written++;
    }
    return written;
}

int consumer()
{
    int read = 0;
    for (;;) {
        test_t mytest(3);
        if (object.read([&mytest](const test_t& test) {
            mytest = test;
        })) {
            read++;
            // Here go expensive calculations
            std::cout << mytest.x << '\n';
            assert(mytest.y != 0);
        } else if (stop_consuming) {
            return read;
        } else {
            // Should not happen unless only a single hardware thread is
            // available for both producer and consumer, as seems to be the case
            // on Coliru for example.
            std::cout << "Oh boy, the producer was too slow!\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    stop_consuming = false;
    auto t1 = std::async(std::launch::async, producer);
    auto t2 = std::async(std::launch::async, consumer);
    int written = t1.get();
    stop_consuming = true;
    int read = t2.get();

    std::cout << "produced = " << to_produce << "\n"
        "written = " << written << "\n"
        "read = consumed = " << read << '\n';
}
```

Sample output:

```
...
9908795
9908803
9908812
9908822
9908832
9908842
9908852
9908861
9908872
9908881
9908891
9908898
9908907
9908917
9908928
9908938
9908948
produced = 10000000
written = 37374
read = consumed = 37374
```

Comment: Your question might be valid as is, but you should really provide a minimal complete working program, and not just your class.

Comment: You're right, I'll add my test case.

Comment: Oh wow I forgot to initialize `occupied_`. There needs to be a member initializer or a constructor that sets it to false. Also copy constructor and assignment operator should probably be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

### Build on top of the standard library, not along

You didn't specify which version of the standard you target. If it is the most recent one, then you have in [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) the tool to avoid explicit memory management and keep the benefit of uninitialized, local storage.

Even if not, a self-contained object handler probably won't bring anything worth renouncing standard tools such as `std::unique_ptr`. That you didn't notice that your program would leak resources if the given `Functor`, or `T`'s constructor, threw an exception, or even if a `write` isn't `read`, is a proof of this wise principle: don't reinvent memory management tools.

If you really want to provide your own memory manager, make it a dedicated, RAII based class, and then compose your `spsc_object` from it and an `atomic`.

### Avoid code duplication

You don't need to have two `write` methods, and two `read` methods even less. `read` already uses a template argument, meaning that `Functor&` will adapt to either `const Functor&` or `Functor&`. For the `write` method, you can introduce a template argument to get into template deduction context and benefit from a forwarding reference.

### Don't clutter variable names with underscores

Classes are meant to qualify names and avoid conflicts, so keep your names informative and beautiful.

With all that in mind, here's what I'd suggest:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <atomic>
#include <optional>

template<typename T>
class spsc_object {

    std::optional<T> value;
    std::atomic_bool occupied;

public:
    template <typename U>
    bool write(U&& object) {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<U, T>);
        if (!occupied.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            value = std::forward<U>(object);
            occupied.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    template<typename Functor>
    bool read(Functor&& functor) {
        if (!occupied.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) 
            return false;
        functor(*value);
        value.reset();
        occupied.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Re "Don't clutter [member] variable names with [trailing] underscores" — I'd disagree. The advantage of uglifying your member-data names is that you can write e.g. `void set_value(T value) { value_ = value; }` in a natural way. It's a really easy way to never worry about shadowing again, and thereby save those few extra brain cells to devote to more productive tasks.

Comment: Also, complete nit, but `std::is_convertible_v<U, T>` raises a tiny red flag because it's using a perfect-forwarding reference in a non-perfect-forwarding context. You meant `std::is_convertible_v<U&&, T>`, or even more relevantly, `std::is_assignable_v<T&, U&&>`.  The further you go down that road, though, the more you can't avoid worrying about the behavior of `mySpscObject.write(std::nullopt)`... :)

Comment: @papagaga I guess you are right, I should put more thought into object lifetime and exception safety. But I don't quite like the `std::optional` approach as it incurs additional overhead because the "occupied" state is duplicated. Also it requires T to have an assignment operator which is a stronger requirement than being copyable or movable by construction in my opinion.

Comment: What I really do like though is the template approach to reduce code duplication!

Comment: Regarding exception safety I think that exceptions in write or read are still not safe because the atomic is not released afterwards. But I could be wrong. One would have to make a RAII wrapper around the atomic or catch and re-throw. Both seem like quite a hassle for tiny reward, so I will likely settle with additional requirements for the user: noexcept copy/move construction, noexcept functors, reading the last value before destruction. I could statically enforce the noexcepts using `std::is_nothrow_...`. Not always being destructible reminds me of `std::thread` which should be fine imo.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I also like the trailing underscores because when editing a method, I immediately see which variables are private members.

Comment: @purefanatic: you don't need to release 'the atomic'. I don't believe it allocates memory in the first place, and if it did, its destructor would be called automatically. That's the beauty of RAII.